# Why I can't add flutter dialogflow dependencies on pub spec.yml

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dialogflow-es, pubspec

I'm trying to implement chatbot on flutter and I'm trying to add dependencies "flutter_dialogflow: ^0.1.3" in the pub spec.yaml and got error. Can anyone help me how to fix it? [image: The error]

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have run into a dependency incompatibility. if you have more than 5 or 6 dependencies it will be harder to find where this issue comes from. best option to will be,

1. Upgrade Flutter to the latest Version.
2. Upgrade all the dependencies to the latest Version. refer [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) when upgrading

Comment: yes I think I have update the dependencies to the latest version. But it's still got error. @Srilal Sachintha